# How to set background colour on Open GL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, blending

I am currently playing about with lesson 08 here

http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

I would like to change the background colour from black to white. In order to do this at the start of onDrawFrame() I have called

gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

This does indeed set a white background screen, but also results in nothing else showing up on the screen! Clearly this is therefore an incorrect method, but why, and how do I fix it?!

Many thanks in advance.

Edit (5 days later): Does nobody know at all?!!

Comment: Did it actually set a white background? Should be red.

Comment: sorry I meant to write gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Answer (score 8):

The white screen is because you have set the alpha value to 0.0f.

The parameter signature is:-
`gl.glClearColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)` where floats are any value between 0.0 to 1.0.

More the float value of alpha more opaque the screen is.

Answer (score 3):

After you call gl.glClearColor(), redraw everything else. gl.glClearColor() does not change background color, it simply fills the screen with white color (which in effect erases everything you've previously drawn).

Comment: I am redrawing everything, but I still see just white. If I disable blending and enable depth testing instead then it works perfectly. So clearly it is some problem related to blending...